# How can I say to a dialog in javaFX to not close the window when i click on a button

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently new on javaFX project. This is my first use of the Dialog in javaFX class.
When I click on an apply button, I would like to retrieve the information in the fields I put, but without closing the window. Currently, as soon as I press a button, it closes the window. Do you know how I should proceed? Thank you in advance

```
    //Init
    this.dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Propriété");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Veuillez entrer les valeurs que vous désirez");
    ButtonType buttonOk = new ButtonType("Ok",ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    ButtonType buttonCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    ButtonType buttonApply = new ButtonType("Apply", ButtonData.APPLY);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonOk,buttonCancel,buttonApply);

    //UI
    final GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(6); 
    gridPane.setVgap(6); 
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(6)); 
    TextField size  = new TextField(); 
    ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    TextField rotate = new TextField();
    size.setText(null); 
    rotate.setText(null);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Size :"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(size, 1, 0); 
    gridPane.add(new Label("Color :"), 0, 1);   
    gridPane.add(colorPicker, 1, 1); 
    gridPane.add(new Label("Rotate :"), 0, 2); 
    gridPane.add(rotate, 1, 2); 

    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(gridPane);
    dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> { 
        if (dialogButton == buttonApply) {
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            result.add(size.getText());
            result.add(colorPicker.getValue().toString());
            result.add(rotate.getText());
            return result;
        }
        if(dialogButton == buttonCancel) {
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return null;
    });
```

I try that with the help of the documentation, but always pointerNull on my button :

```
        //Création de la boite de dialogue
    this.dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Edition des propriétés");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Veuillez entrer les valeurs que vous désirez");
    ButtonType buttonOk = new ButtonType("Ok",ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    ButtonType buttonCancel = new ButtonType("Annuler", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    ButtonType buttonApply = new ButtonType("Appliquer", ButtonData.APPLY);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonOk,buttonCancel,buttonApply);

    final Button btApply = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.APPLY);
    btApply.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
        event.consume();
     });
```

Comment: Isn't this covered in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), under "Dialog Validation / Intercepting Button Actions"? Did you try that?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the answer. I try it, but not with success. Always NullPointerException.
I get the Button like the document said, but it is always null.

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempt to do that.

Comment: Done ! my btApply is always null.

Comment: Surely you need `lookupButton(buttonApply)`, not `lookupButton(ButtonType.APPLY)`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't think we should put the variable directly, just his ButtonData. It works. Thank you very much ! I look a little stupid with this misunderstanding...